# How to run blacklist using an RPC client

Tags: corda

There is an example here: https://github.com/corda/blacklist.

First I have run the node using
1. gradlew deployNodes
2. Start the nodes by running runnodes
3. gradlew uploadBlacklist

It showed following message: 
[image]

Now what need to do? How can we see the uploaded and downloaded file. If I open localhost:10006 in browser it is not showing anything.

How to reuse that code in some other project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The attachment is referenced in building a transaction:

```
val txBuilder = TransactionBuilder(notary)
        .addOutputState(agreementState, AGREEMENT_CONTRACT_ID)
        .addCommand(agreeCmd, agreeCmdRequiredSigners)
        .addAttachment(untrustedPartiesAttachment)
```

Once it is added to the transaction, it can be referenced within the contract:

```
val attachmentJar = attachment.openAsJAR()
while (attachmentJar.nextEntry.name != "blacklist.txt") {
    // Calling `attachmentJar.nextEntry` causes us to scroll through the JAR.
}
val blacklistedCompanies = mutableListOf<String>()
val bufferedReader = attachmentJar.bufferedReader()
var company = bufferedReader.readLine()
while (company != null) {
    blacklistedCompanies.add(company)
    company = bufferedReader.readLine()
}
```

You could also extend the client to download the attachment via RPC. See the `downloadAttachment` method.

Comment: I don't understand "extend the client". How to use downloadAttachment method? How can we see the uploaded and downloaded file. If I open localhost:10006 in browser it is not showing anything. What are the steps needed once build successful?